# How to add to array on successful barcode scan?

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic barcode scanner - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

What I need to do is run the scanner, look for a certain qr code that I will create, if that qr code is found then add a timestamp to a list/array.

I thought to create a qr code that is a simple string, then create an if statement that checks to see if the scan result matches the string, however I get an error saying -

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'BarcodeScanResult' and 'String'
```

So I assume this idea wont work. What is solution that will work?

Comment: post your code where you assign

Comment: ScanCode() : any{
  this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    
    var inputString = "testData";
    
    if( barcodeData == inputString)
        
   }, (err) => {

   });
  };

Answer (score 1):

As the error says , You are trying to compare two different types ,  access the **`text`** property of **`barcodeData`** , need to do like this

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
     let inputString = "testData";
     if( barcodeData.text === inputString){

     }
    }, (err) => {
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, then to add the time stamp it will just be something like -
    ScanCode() : any{
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {

    var successfulScans = new Array();
    var inputString = "testData";
    
    if( barcodeData.text == inputString){
      successfulScans.push(DateTime);
      console.log("Success");
      console.log(successfulScans);
     } else {
      console.log("Doesnt Match");
     }
        
    }, (err) => {

    });
    };

Is that correct?

Comment: yeah if successfulScans is an array of date , above should work

Comment: Ive just done - var successfulScans = new Array();

How do I make it an array of date? I tested it, and its not adding dates as expected.

Comment: you need to use let/const with typescript also declared as let successfulScans  : any = [];

Comment: Perfect so this created the array, ive tested it with console.log(successfulScans.length);
No matter how many correct scans its length is always 1.

Comment: you may recreating the array each time

Comment: Ahh this would make sense. But if I create the array outside the this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData)
function then it gives errors.

Comment: declare it at the above constructor

Comment: When I add it to - 
constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner)

I get an error when using it saying "Cannot find name 'successfulScans'

Comment: you need to use this.successfulScans

Comment: If I add this. before calling it, example - this.successfulScans.push(DateTime);
It says it doesnt exist on type 'homepage', whilst the array is created in the above constuctor

Comment: search for the error on google and you will find a solution :)  time to sleep now :)

Comment: Found it :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, it is the **text** property you are looking for, the **barcodeData** object looks like this:

```
{
 text: "The code that was scanned",
 format: "Code format",
 cancelled: true
}
```

I might go bit beyond scope but could it be something like this you are looking for?, this checks if the scanned barcode is recognized, if so, the barcode along with a Unix timestamp is be added to an Array!

```
let timeStamps = new Array<any>();
let ts = new Date().valueOf();
let qrCodes: Array<string> = ["5030917215094", "5051892205498"];
let scope = this;

scope.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    let barCode = barcodeData.text;

    if (scope.qrCodes.indexOf(barCode)) {
        scope.timeStamps.push(
            {
                "timestamp": new Date().valueOf(),
                "barCode": barCode
            }
        );
    }
}, (err) => {
    // An error occurred
});
```

Comment: I am trying to test this out, but when I add the code all the "let" parts of the syntax give "unexpected token" errors.

Comment: let is an ES6 feature also my snippet is in TypeScript , for ES5 change "let" to "var"  also change "new Array<any>();" into ""new Array();"